# How to declare + call a jQuery function from inside other jQuery functions without it being related to an event

Tags: jquery, function

Maybe this is obvious but none of the answers here have helped me so far. I have several jquery functions that execute similar code. One piece of code, in particular, is exactly the same, so I defined it separately and want each function to call it at some point during execution (so the call is not related to a specific event, just want to normally execute that piece of code).

The function I want to call is named "closeAll". This is one of the several 'parent' functions that call it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#openNav").click(function(){
        closeAll();                 /*function call*/
        $("#myNav").width("100%");
        $("#Industries-menu").css("color", "#ff5e5e");
        $("#ll-link-section").show();
        $("#lr-wrapper1").show();
    });
});
```

This is the closeAll function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function closeAll(){
        $("#Industries-menu").css("color","white");
        $("#lr-wrapper1").hide();
        $("#Services-menu").css("color","white");
        $("#lr-wrapper2").hide();
        $("#AboutUs-menu").css("color","white");
        $("#lr-wrapper3").hide();
        $("#Insights-menu").css("color","white");
        $("#lr-wrapper4").hide();
        $("#Careers-menu").css("color","white");
        $("#lr-wrapper5").hide();
    });
});
```

I guess I am missing something when it comes to calling a function without a trigger event. I had written the same code using raw javascript (it was working) and transformed it to jQuery to get used to it, but it is not working anymore. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Keep the function `closeAll()` outside of `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't be allowed due to scope. The function defined inside `$(document).ready()` is accessible only inside that `ready()` scope but not from another `ready()` scope.

As I have mentioned in the comment of the original post, if your `closeAll()` is a simple function do not enclose it in another `$(document).ready()`.

There are several options:

- Keep `closeAll()` function inside the same `$(document).ready()` function instead of another (same local scope)
- Declare `clearAll()` outside of `$(document).ready()` as a plain function (global scope)
- Declare a variable `clearAll` outside `$(document).ready()` and then modify this to attach a function. This function is accessible from anyhwhere. (global scope)

```
   var x;
   $(document).ready(function () {
   x = function(){
   }
   // Do something else
   });
```

Here is an example where the button `click` event calls `doSomething()` function that is defined outside of `ready()`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("ready");
        $("#b1").click(function () {
            console.log("clicked");
            doSomething();
            $("#e1").text("From Button Event");
        });
    });

    function doSomething() {
        console.log("something")
        $("#e2").text("Done Something");
    }

</script>
<h2 id="e1">Default</h2>
<h3 id="e2">Default</h3>
<button id="b1">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't very aware of the scope issue.

Answer (score 2):

The function `closeAll` in your code is not accessible from where it is called.

It's because of difference in scopes of the calling function and the function to be called.

You can do 2 things here.

First, **keep the calling function and the function to be called in the same scope**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#openNav").click(function(){ 
        closeAll(); /*function call*/ 
        $("#myNav").width("100%");
        $("#Industries-menu").css("color", "#ff5e5e"); 
        $("#ll-link-section").show(); 
        $("#lr-wrapper1").show();
    }); 

    function closeAll(){ 
        $("#Industries-menu").css("color","white"); 
       $("#lr-wrapper1").hide();
       $("#Services-menu").css("color","white");
       $("#lr-wrapper2").hide(); 
       $("#AboutUs-menu").css("color","white");
       $("#lr-wrapper3").hide(); 
       $("#Insights-menu").css("color","white");
       $("#lr-wrapper4").hide(); 
       $("#Careers-menu").css("color","white");
       $("#lr-wrapper5").hide(); 
    }
});
```

Second, **keep the calling function in the child scope of the scope of the function to be called**

```
// Parent scope
function closeAll(){ 
    $("#Industries-menu").css("color","white"); 
    $("#lr-wrapper1").hide();
    $("#Services-menu").css("color","white");
    $("#lr-wrapper2").hide(); 
    $("#AboutUs-menu").css("color","white");
    $("#lr-wrapper3").hide(); 
    $("#Insights-menu").css("color","white");
    $("#lr-wrapper4").hide(); 
    $("#Careers-menu").css("color","white");
    $("#lr-wrapper5").hide(); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    // Child scope
    $("#openNav").click(function(){ 
        closeAll(); /*function call*/ 
        $("#myNav").width("100%");
        $("#Industries-menu").css("color", "#ff5e5e"); 
        $("#ll-link-section").show(); 
        $("#lr-wrapper1").show();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps :)